# Using oauth with node-webkit

Tags: node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0, node-webkit

Our application is built with node-webkit and we'd like to add an authentication layer.
We could use node-webkit as a regular browser and hit our website (ie redirecting to http://www.oursite.com) but we'd loose all the interest of webkit. The point here is to authenticate the user from the start, ie with the local url which should look like *file:///C:/Users/ALEXAN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/nw7628_20315/index.html*

According to [this question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/15419985/node-webkit-facebook-integration?noredirect=1#comment21806477_15419985), we can use fb authentication should work.

But is there a way to use oauth? The two solutions that came to my mind are:

- using an iframe inside the page but oauth providers refuses such requests
- Calling directly oauth with our local return url (file:///...) but redirections to local files are forbiden too in browsers (hence in webkit).

It might be a pretty general question but anything I'm missing with oauth/node-webkit?
If it's impossible, how would you authenticate users in such an app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use client-side oauth, make it through the "server side" of node-webkit. That means, you can popup a window, redirect it, close it when you are done. All the necessary information you need to pass using the `request` library, or API SDK for the Facebook oauth.

Part of this process I've posted in here  [window.open without popup blocker using AJAX and manipulating the window.location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361813/window-open-without-popup-blocker-using-ajax-and-manipulating-the-window-locatio)

Comment: I haven't the time to implement your method yet but it seems pretty clever.
Just one thought: you can't see the url in a popup as well (compared to an iframe). Is that a security hole?

Comment: well, I guess it is. newer browsers ignore the location=0 by default, just to make you be able to see the location. IE of course hides the location as expected. at least in chrome and firefox, that isn't an issue